# Flutter: CupertinoRefreshControl does not dismiss

Tags: flutter

I built the following small test code to demonstrate the problem I'm experiencing on Flutter:

[image]

From the gif, you can see that the app pulls to refresh and the slivers text are updated from "Hello Refresh" to "Bye Refresh", however, the CupertinoRefreshControl loading icon does not disappear after the text changes.
I had expected the loading icon to disappear when the new data is loaded into the Sliver:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ui';

class _RefreshTestState extends State<RefreshTest> {

  bool flag = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    // TODO: implement build
    return new CupertinoPageScaffold(
      //i will need to convert this to a sliver list to make this work properly.
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFEFEFF4),
      child: new CustomScrollView(slivers: <Widget>[
        new CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(largeTitle: new Text('TESTING'),),
        new CupertinoRefreshControl(onRefresh: () {
          return new Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1))
            ..then((_) => setState(() {
              if (flag) {
                flag = false;
              } else {
                flag = true;
              }
            }));
        }),
        new SliverSafeArea(
          top: false,
          sliver: new SliverList(
            delegate: new SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                  (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return flag? new Text("Hello Refresh.") : new Text("Bye refresh");
              },
              childCount: 2,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ]),
    );
  }


}
class RefreshTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  }

  @override
  _RefreshTestState createState() => new _RefreshTestState();

}
```

I see a github thread has been started for this issue as well however, no solution has yet been posted: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17474

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was subsequently discovered that when the list was not long enough, the refresh spinning icon will not disappear when you pull to refresh.
This was solved with flutter update a few month's later so with the new flutter, this issue will no longer appear.